# Django ModelChoice field is set to required=False but is still required in the browser

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates

```py
class One(forms.ModelForm):

    space = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=models.Space.objects.none(), required=False)

    mode_specific = False

    class Meta:
        model = OneModel
        id_fields = ["name", "description", "space"]

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(One, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # this returns false
        print(self.fields["space"].required)
```

But on the template, the "space" is still required, I'm not sure what the issue is.

Comment: can you show us the model you are using for this form?

Comment: Also, you didn't declare a model?  I don't think model forms will work if you don't declare the model they represent in `Meta`.

Comment: Hi @CalebGoodman I actually declared a model and made the space field null=True, blank=True

Comment: Where was the model declared?  You didn't declare it in the code you provided?

Comment: @CalebGoodman I just updated the question

Comment: post the HTML ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste the below code in your **init** method of create and edit form classes. Try this out and confirm.

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
    super(One, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields.values():
        self.fields['space'].required = False
```